# Is the creation of secondary accounts for reposting a closed question considered circumventing?

Tags: discussion

Over in the [discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.js) tag, there have been a few instances where users post a poorly written question (which gets downvoted and closed), and the user then creates an alternate account to then repost the same question. The repost *may* be slightly improved based on feedback given in the original post. However, the question still has clear issues, such as lack of clarity or debugging details.

It is clear to see that these users are very new to programming and may be trying to tackle complex projects without having enough knowledge and experience. This is likely the reason they are unable to provide their own code or struggle to explain what they are trying to accomplish.

That being said, it is still wrong to repost the same question through a different account... Right?

There are now a few returning users to the tag that are reposting their poorly questions for a second chance at being answered. What should be done about these alternate accounts? The reposts themselves get downvoted and flagged just as the original. But should secondary accounts also be reported for circumvention, or are their actions inline with Stack Overflow's rules?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. It's considered ban evasion

Comment: I just sampled the last 10 questions in that tag. The quality is surprisingly good. So it is not even a norm in that tag to write poorly.

Comment: There is also [a tag for Discord itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord).

Comment: “But should secondary accounts also be reported for circumvention, or are their actions inline with Stack Overflow's rules?” - Yes; “That being said, it is still wrong to repost the same question through a different account... Right?”- Yes; “What should be done about these alternate accounts?” - Immediately deleted and the original account suspended.

Answer (score 11):

*Normally* if a user is reposting a question on a new account this is to avoid a question ban and is against the rules. Reposting questions on the *same* account is frowned upon enough, and effectively against the rules, however, intentionally avoiding a question ban *is* most certainly against the rules. This is because they have created a new account to avoid a limitation placed on their other account; although having multiple accounts isn't against the rules creating a second one to be able to do something you couldn't normally do (such as posting a question in this case) *is* against the rules.

If you see a question that has been posted by a (new) user that is clearly the same as another question posted by a different user (that other question likely closed (and probably deleted shortly before the new one was posted)) then raise a moderator flag on the new question, and explain that it appears the user is trying to avoid a question ban, and link to their original question in the flag. You'll probably want to VTC the question as well, as if their last question was closed, the (exact) duplicate should be too.

Most likely, when a moderator handles the flag, their new account will be deleted, and the old account may also have restrictions imposed on it.

Comment: Just for extra information - even when a user doesn't (intentionally) try to bypass a ban by creating a new account, they still circumvent site systems and rules. There are rate limits on how often a question can be posted, which they might be bypassing. Also the close/reopen process. With that said, asking the same question from multiple accounts does also mean that the question ban algorithm will not go into effect, either.

Comment: Some of those rate limits are IP based, @VLAZ . I *think* the rate limit on posting questions is one that is IP based, so the user would need to also change their IP.